# React Conetxt with useReducer + Typescript - 'No overload matches this call'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I have the following reducer code:

```
import { IState } from "./initialState";
import { TAction } from "./actions";
import * as types from './types';

const reducer = (state: IState, action: TAction): IState => {
    const { type, payload } = action;
    switch (type) {
        case types.API_REQUEST:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true
            };
        case types.API_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                data: payload
            };
        case types.API_ERROR:
            return {
                ...state,
                error: payload
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default reducer;
```

Usage in component:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useReducer } from "react";
import Context from './newsContext';
import reducer from "./store/reducer";
import initialState from "./store/initialState";
function News(): JSX.Element {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
    return (
        <Context.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
        </Context.Provider>);
}
```

Context:

```
import initialState, { IState } from "./store/initialState";
import { TAction } from "./store/actions";
import { createContext, Dispatch } from "react";

interface IContextProps {
    state: IState,
    dispatch: Dispatch<TAction>;
}

const Context = createContext<IContextProps>({
    dispatch: () => {
        // Dispatch initial value
    },
    state: initialState
});

export default Context;
```

My compiler shows ts error:

```
TypeScript error in reactor-ts/src/news/News.tsx(7,42):
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 5, '(reducer: ReducerWithoutAction<any>, initializerArg: any, initializer?: undefined): [any, DispatchWithoutAction]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(state: IState, action: TAction) => IState' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReducerWithoutAction<any>'.
  Overload 2 of 5, '(reducer: Reducer<any, any>, initialState: any, initializer?: undefined): [any, Dispatch<any>]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(state: IState, action: TAction) => IState' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Reducer<any, any>'.
      Types of parameters 'action' and 'action' are incompatible.
        Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'.
          The intersection 'TAction' was reduced to 'never' because property 'type' has conflicting types in some constituents.  TS2769
```

Any idea what I'm missing - why the compiler fails?

Comment: Instead of adding `IState`, try to give default value to the state param. `const reducer = (state = initialState, action: TAction) => {`. See if this solves the issue

Comment: @Dilshan Thanks but no :(

Comment: Added git with the full code

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue - wow it was so hard to understand from the compiler error.

My code was:

```
export type TAction = IApiRequest & IApiSuccess & IApiError;
```

But had to be:

```
export type TAction = IApiRequest | IApiSuccess | IApiError;
```

The request can be one of the types, not all of them.

Comment: Oh. By the way I added a pull request with some better approach to manage your state. First I though you are using Redux. Then I realized its context API. take a look

Comment: Thanks @Dilshan, can you share why it's better?